# How do I make a UBER-API web request in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

We're developping an automobile costs calculator and we'd like to compare car costs with UBER's for a certain city. I've checked on the [UBER API](https://developer.uber.com/docs/trip-experiences/references/api/v1.2/products-product_id-get) but I didn't get how does it work for Javascript.

How do I make a web request in javascript?

Do we need to register/authenticate or can we make an anonymous simple information request?

Comment: It works in Javascript precisely the same way it does for everything else, you call the API using a web request. What are you asking specifically? If it's "how do I make a web request in javascript?" then please update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Please be sure to check out the Terms of Use for the Uber API before you proceed with a price comparison app.

Comment: @Clint as requested, I remade the question! Thank you

Comment: The OP question is relevant. UBER API documentation is poor and has only a `curl` command as request and no further information on how to proceed otherwise in other environments.

Comment: @joao_pimentel that's legitimate on their behalf, it's just a request over HTTP, so the question really is just "how to make an API request in Javascript?"

Comment: @Aónio that's great, thanks, now, can you clarify whether you're using just javascript, or are you using JQuery / Angular / what ever? The best approach will depend on your environment.

Comment: @Clint, I'm using either Jquery or Javascript. Both are ok. Thank you